# Is this SOQL query possible?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

```
List<Account> accs = [select Id,Name from Account where Name in: Trigger.New];
```

It gives me the following error :-
Invalid bind expression type of Account for column of type String.

Comment: This is actually feasible, could you give a try with query like this: "select Id,Name from Account where Id in: Trigger.New"

Comment: I want to filter duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`Trigger.new` is holding reference to the records changing, not a `String`.

If you want to filter your SOQL by a list of Names, you should use a local variable such as:

```
List<String> accountNames = new List<String>{'AccountNameOne', 'AccountNameTwo'};
List<Account> accs = [
    select Id,
    Name from Account 
    where Id in :Trigger.New 
    and Name in :accountNames];
```

In saying this, I am not sure why you really need to query the changed records as you have direct access to the row, unless running in `after` and the field never changed.

## Update

After your recent comment under the question, you are looking to prevent duplicate Accounts by Name. This can be achieved using a duplicate rule, see [standard Account Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_standard_account_rule.htm&type=5)

Comment: The trigger occurs before insert.I am trying find duplicates by Name. If they exist cancel insertion.

Comment: You should use Duplicate Rules instead then.